# Trigger to raise raise an application error with a meaningful message if og_id refers to a cancelled Olympic Game

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

These are the following tables I have created:

```
 CREATE TABLE Country 
(
 country_id NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 country_name VARCHAR(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT check_country_id CHECK (country_id > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE OG_Type 
(
 og_type_id NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 og_type_title VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Olympic_Game 
(
 og_id NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 og_type_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
 og_year NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 og_website VARCHAR(150),
 og_cancel VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 country_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT check_og_id CHECK (og_id > 0),
 CONSTRAINT check_og_year_og_type UNIQUE (og_type_id, og_year),
 CONSTRAINT fk_og_type_id FOREIGN KEY(og_type_id) REFERENCES OG_Type(og_type_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_country_id FOREIGN KEY(country_id) REFERENCES Country(country_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Sport 
(
 sport_id NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
 sport_title VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT check_sport_id CHECK (sport_id > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE Event 
(
 event_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
 sport_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
 og_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
 event_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 event_team  VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 no_per_team  NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
 event_gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT check_event_id CHECK (event_id > 0),
 CONSTRAINT check_event_title_sport_id_og_id_event_team_event_gender UNIQUE (event_title, sport_id, og_id, event_team, event_gender),
 CONSTRAINT check_event_team CHECK (event_team IN ('Y','N')),
 CONSTRAINT check_event_team_no_per_team CHECK ((event_team='N' AND no_per_team=1) OR (event_team='Y' AND no_per_team>1)),
 CONSTRAINT check_event_gender CHECK (event_gender IN ('M','F')),
 CONSTRAINT fk_sport_id FOREIGN KEY(sport_id) REFERENCES Sport(sport_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_og_id FOREIGN KEY(og_id) REFERENCES Olympic_Game(og_id)
);
```

After creating these 4 tables, I have inserted the values for these 4 tables:

```
insert into country(country_id,country_name) values (country_seq.nextval,'FRA');
insert into country(country_id,country_name) values (country_seq.nextval,'GBR');
insert into country(country_id,country_name) values (country_seq.nextval,'GRE');
insert into country(country_id,country_name) values (country_seq.nextval,'USA');

insert into og_type(og_type_id, og_type_title) values(og_type_seq.nextval,'Summer');
insert into og_type(og_type_id, og_type_title) values(og_type_seq.nextval,'Winter');
insert into og_type(og_type_id, og_type_title) values(og_type_seq.nextval,'Special');
insert into og_type(og_type_id, og_type_title) values(og_type_seq.nextval,'Youth');
insert into og_type(og_type_id, og_type_title) values(og_type_seq.nextval,'Senior');

insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,1,1896,null,'N',3);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,1,1900,null,'N',1);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,1,1904,null,'N',4);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,1,1908,'op1908.org','N',2);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,2,1924,null,'N',1);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,1,1944,null,'Y',2);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,3,1944,null,'Y',2);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,4,1944,null,'Y',2);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,5,1944,null,'Y',2);
insert into olympic_game(og_id,og_type_id,og_year,og_website,og_cancel,country_id) values(og_seq.nextval,1,2012,'https://www.olympic.org/london-2012','N',2);

insert into sport(sport_id,sport_title) values(sport_seq.nextval, 'Track and Field');
insert into sport(sport_id,sport_title) values(sport_seq.nextval, 'Tennis');
insert into sport(sport_id,sport_title) values(sport_seq.nextval, 'Speed Skating');

insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,1,'100m','N',1,'M');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,2,1,'Double','Y',2,'M');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,2,'200m','N',1,'M');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,2,2,'Single','N',1,'M');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,3,'400m','N',1,'F');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,3,'100m','N',1,'F');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,4,'1500m','N',1,'F');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,3,5,'800m','N',1,'F');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,10,'100m','N',1,'M');
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,10,'100m','N',1,'F');
```

Now this is the question:
**Create a trigger called TR_event_on_cancelled_og. This trigger fires before inserting or updating a row in the Event table. The trigger should raise an application error with a meaningful message if og_id refers to a cancelled Olympic Game.**

Now this is the solution I came up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_event_on_cancelled  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON Event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    v_og_cancel Olympic_Game.og_cancel%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT og_cancel INTO V_og_cancel 
    FROM Olympic_Game, Event
    WHERE Olympic_Game.og_id = Event.og_id
    AND Olympic_Game.og_id = :NEW.og_id;
    IF (v_og_cancel = 'N')
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'This Olympic Game is cancelled already');
    END IF;
END;
END;

Trigger TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED compiled
```

The trigger is compiled successfully but the problem is when I was trying to test the trigger I got the following error messages:

```
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,8,'400m','N',1,'F');

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "OG_JC480454.TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OG_JC480454.TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) values(event_seq.nextval,1,2,'400m','N',1,'F');

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "OG_JC480454.TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OG_JC480454.TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Where did I exactly go wrong ? ...
It would be really helpful if the trigger solution code is provided.

Comment: Please learn to lay your code out in a manner which is easy to read, especially by using indentation to indicate blocks. You may be happy with your code the way it is but you should make the effort when asking other people to read it. Also, your Trigger body is wrapped in an unnecessary BEGIN ... END block; it doesn't do any harm, it just trips people up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that your trigger code is selecting from EVENT. It doesn't need to do this because the rule applies only to the current event you're inserting or updating.

So:

```
SELECT og_cancel INTO V_og_cancel 
FROM Olympic_Game
WHERE Olympic_Game.og_id = :NEW.og_id;
```

Incidentally, the next test looks wrong:

```
IF (v_og_cancel = 'N')
```

Unless you're using Y/N flags in an odd manner this would be testing if the Games have **not** been cancelled. Surely that should be `= 'Y'`?

---

> " I want to get this error message"

I have created an Oracle LiveSQL with your data and my version of the trigger. [Find it here (but you will need an OTN account to look at it)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f5umhbcnh4kkkhcjs6o5xzzkd).

When I attempt this INSERT ...

```
insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) 
values(event_seq.nextval,2,9,'Double','Y',2,'M');
```

it fails on

```
ORA-20001: This Olympic Game is cancelled already
```

Quite rightly, because the games where `og_id = 9` has `og_cancel='Y'`.

Now you say you're getting `ORA-20977: the game was cancelled`. That's a user-defined error (in the range -20999 to -20000. So it's some part of **your codebase** which is hurling it.

If you don't know what part it is you will need to dig into your data dictionary. I can't solve that for you. But here's a thought: have you got more than one trigger on the table? Your homework says to create a trigger called `TR_event_on_cancelled_og` but the code you published does `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_event_on_cancelled`. Perhaps you previously created a trigger with the other name, and that's what is raising the `ORA-20977`.

Comment: I fixed the code as you have suggested. Then I tried testing the code:  insert into event(event_id,sport_id,og_id,event_title,event_team,no_per_team,event_gender) 
values(event_seq.nextval,2,9,'Double','Y',2,'M');                                         But I'm not getting the error message that I want.                                       ORA-06512: at "OG_JC480454.TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED_OG", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OG_JC480454.TR_EVENT_ON_CANCELLED_OG'

Comment: I'm also getting this error as well. SQL                                                    Error: ORA-20977: the game was cancelled

Comment: If you look at my Trigger code:                                                                        IF (v_og_cancel = 'N')
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'This Olympic Game is cancelled already');
    END IF;                                                                                                    I want to get this error message but I'm not getting this error message

Comment: Yes, you were correct ... I renamed the trigger name from TR_event_on_cancelled to TR_event_on_cancelled_og. Now, it is working perfectly.